# WebJobs SDK - Omitting the AzureJobsDashboard connection string

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

Has anything changed recently in the Azure WebJobs SDK around the omission of the AzureJobsDashboard connection string? Up until recently if this connection string was left out the WebJobs dashboard would not show / store any invocation logs etc. Now if this connection string is removed the WebJob will not start at all... Has anyone else noticed this or found a work around?

I do not want any queue messages logged in the invocation logs so would be interested to hear if anyone else has achieved something similar?

Thanks, Phil.

Comment: Phil are you seeing change of behavior from 0.2.0-alpha2 to 0.3.0-beta? Also are you setting the AzureJobsDashboard ConnectionString value to be "" or you do not have AzureJobsDashboard ConnectionString at all?

Comment: Hi Pranav, apologies for the delay in getting back to you. I am currently running 0.3.1-beta of the SDK and I have the AzureJobsDashboard connectionstring set as "" in the web.config. I have also tried to set the AzureJobsDashboard to "" in the Azure portal but it will not allow me to save an empty string. I will try reverting to 0.2.0-alpha2 and see if removing the AzureJobsDashboard works with this version.

Comment: You need to set the dashboard connectionstring explicitly to empty in code as follows:var config = new JobHostConfiguration() { DashboardConnectionString = "" };
var host = new JobHost(config);
host.RunAndBlock();

Comment: I'm having the same problem and tried Pranav's suggestion for explicitly setting to empty in code. It's still not working - giving this error: Failed to validate Microsoft Azure Jobs dashboard connection string: Microsoft Azure Storage account connection string is missing or empty. Any other ideas?

Comment: Same problem.  I am trying to test a WebJob locally before I deploy it, so a website does not yet exist to host my application, therefore there is no key to put into the connection string.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem, but it solved by:

1. Set `AzureWebJobsDashboard` in config file to avoid the error, then
2. Set it to `null` in code to stop logging.

```
JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
config.DashboardConnectionString = null;
```

and that works with me

Answer (score 0):

I found the same error with webjob. When I tried to tested with console app with azure sdk. I am using azure sdk version 1.8. According a message displaying on web job log page now we need to put a connection string with name "AzureWebJobsDashboard" while it was earlier "AzureJobsDashboard". So I have changed it tried to azure sdk but same error. So what I have done that I have kept both connection string with same value i.e. one is "AzureWebJobsDashboard" and other is "AzureJobsDashboard" in the website configuration and now its working perfectly.